# snippet: jQuery syntax highlighter

Tags: jquery

I am using Snippet, a jQuery plugin for highlighting code.

http://www.steamdev.com/snippet/

I got it working correctly for highlighting css, js, php etc. But it does not highlight my HTML. Here is my test page.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9883217/syntaxHighlighter/index.html

any ideas on why it does not highlight my html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is being parsed by the browser.

You need to escape it (replace `<` with `&lt;`, `>` with `&gt;`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

With PHP you can use the function [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlentities.php)

```
<?php
    $str = "Ein 'Anführungszeichen' ist <b>fett</b>";

    // Gibt aus: Ein 'Anf&uuml;hrungszeichen' ist &lt;b&gt;fett&lt;/b&gt;
    echo htmlentities($str);

    // Gibt aus: Ein &#039;Anf&uuml;hrungszeichen&#039; ist &lt;b&gt;fett&lt;/b&gt;
    echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
?>
```